# React использование eval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, функции

Изучаю react и решил сделать простое приложение-калькулятор из двух инпутов для ввода числовых данных и селекта, который позволяет выбрать нужную операцию. За вывод отвечает див. Так как в итоге при попытке это все совместить мы имеет string и получаем строку по типу "2 + 4" а не результат, то думал сделать .eval() и перевести в число принудительно, но React ругается на функции js. Как можно использовать eval в React или более красиво это сделать.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react'


class Calc extends Component {

    constructor (props){

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            firstOperand: 0,
            secondOperand: 0,
            operation: '',
            result: 0
        }

        this.secondOperand = this.secondOperand.bind(this);
        this.firstOperand = this.firstOperand.bind(this);
        this.operation  = this.operation.bind(this);
        this.result = this.result.bind(this);


    }

    firstOperand(event) {
        this.setState({firstOperand: event.target.value})
        this.result()
    }

    secondOperand(event) {
        this.setState({secondOperand: event.target.value})
        this.result()
    }

    operation(event){
        this.setState({operation: event.target.value})
        this.result()
    }

    result(){

    }




    render(){
        return(
            <div>
            <form >

                <input
                type = "number"
                value = {this.state.firstOperand}
                onChange = {this.firstOperand}
                />

                <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.operation}>
                    <option value="+">+</option>
                    <option value="-">-</option>
                    <option value="*">*</option>
                    <option value="/">/</option>
                </select>


                <input
                type = "number"
                value = {this.state.secondOperand}
                onChange = {this.secondOperand}
                />
            </form>


            <div>
               <p>{this.state.result}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Calc
```

Comment: Многие напишут "Нужен код". К сожалению, сейчас возможности его предоставить нету. Нужен просто совет возможно с примером, как добавить в react eval() или как сделать из трех строковых выражений одно математическое. То есть из '2' + '-' + '2' сделать не '2 - 2', а 0

Comment: Я - представитель многих. Нужен код.

Answer (score 1):

Правило `no-eval` включено в eslint-e по умолчанию. Для того чтоб отключить его в коде, достаточно поставить  `// eslint-disable-next-line no-eval` перед строчкой с eval'om:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line no-eval
const result = eval(expression);
```

Желательно понимать что `eval()` отключён по умолчанию не случайно. Он считается опасной функцией и в большинстве случаев можно обойтись без него. Например, в вашем случае, можно воспользоваться вот этой библиотекой: https://github.com/silentmatt/expr-eval

Answer (score 0):

eval использовать в принципе не стоит.

Как вариант, функцию result можно реализовать следующим образом.

```
result() {
  let res;
  switch(this.state.operator) {
    case '+':
      res = this.state.firstOperand + this.state.secondOperand;
    case '-':
      res = this.state.firstOperand - this.state.secondOperand;
    ...
    // остальной код
  }
  this.setState({result: res});
}
```